# How to install a VS plugin in Rider?

Tags: c#, plugins, arcgis, rider

I am trying to switch from Visual Studio to Rider. For that, I need Rider to be able to import a third-party SDK (ArcGIS Pro SKD from Esri). This is available in the Visual Studio Marketplace but not in Rider. I also have a vsix installer package for offline installation. There is no ArcGIS plugins in the Rider marketplace, and if installing it looks like Rider wants it in some packaged  form. The SDK installation contains all sorts of librarys and templates. If i can't install them, it basically renders Rider a useless tool for me.

What are my options here? I am basically assuming that a VS plugin should work in Rider. Is this Assumption flawed?

Comment: Your assumption is flawed, Rider has an entirely different plugin ecosystem than VS.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Esri? They should know better if VS is there only supported tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esri only supports VS 2017 and 2019.

https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/wiki#requirements

You cannot use a .vsix installer with rider so you are out of luck with regard to official channels. You could try creating your own build target in Rider following [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Settings_Toolset_and_Build.html).

You want your Rider build target to point to

"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Esri\ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.11.targets"

or whatever the equivalent is for the version of the Esri SDK you are using.

Good luck.